# Column copy and paste using macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am not familiar with VBA or Macro and I use Microsoft excel quite often.

what's better way to write this? What I want is to copy Column B and paste Column B to right next column and every other column.

For example:

on sheet2, I want B column to be on B column

on sheet3, I want B column to be on C column and clear Column B

on sheet4, I want B column to be on E column and clear Column B

on sheet5, I want B column to be on F column and clear Column B

.

.

.

.
on sheet 26, I want B column to be on Z column and clear column B

on sheet 27, I want B column to be on AA column and clear column B

so on

I have used " Record Macro" to come up with this but I'd like to use VBA programming. what'd be the best way to copy/cut paste columns?

```
Sheets(2).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Sheets(3).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("C:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets(4).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("D:D").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets(5).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("E:E").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets(6).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("F:F").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets(7).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("G:G").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets(8).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("H:H").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets(9).Select
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("I:I").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(i)
            .Columns(2).Copy .Columns(i + 2)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To **clear** column **B** in each sheet:

```
   Sub ytrewq()
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
            With Sheets(i)
                .Columns(2).Copy .Columns(i + 2)
                .Columns(2).Clear
            End With
        Next i
    End Sub
```

**EDIT#2**

This starts on *Sheet3*:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(i)
            .Columns(2).Copy .Columns(i)
            .Columns(2).Clear
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I get rid of Column B after being copied and pasted? And this helped tremendously! Thank you so much!--I edited my question.

Comment: For those who need to know how to clear Column B, add this .Columns(2).ClearContents

Comment: @Chris  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I have noticed tho, my B column on Sheet2 has moved to Column D, which isn't what I want. How can I make Column B stay on Column B on Sheet2? and on Sheet 3, I want Column B on Column C and clear Column B. On sheet4, I want column B on Column D and clear Column B. Im sorry that I confused you. See my edited post. thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Chris  Do you want to start the process to start with *Sheet3* and skip the first two sheets **??**

Comment: Yes. I want to start the process to start with Sheet2. On sheet 2, I want Column B stay as it is. On sheet3, I want Column B to be on Column C and clear column B. On sheet 4, I want column B to be on Column D and clear column B. So on.

Comment: @Chris  See my **EDIT#2**

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Sub to cut down on some of the repetitiveness of your code.

Ex.

```
Sub copyPaste(sheetNum as integer, copyCol as string, pasteCol as string)

    Sheets(sheetNum).Select
    Columns(copyCol).Copy Columns(pasteCol)
    Columns(copyCol).ClearContents

end sub
```